# How to allow empty strings in String.split()?

Tags: java, string, split

I am using [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to split a string. The string I receive has this structure:

```
[data]<US>[data]<US>
```

where `<US>` is the ASCII unit separator (code 0x1F). The code to split is

```
String[] fields = someString.split(String.valueOf(0x1f));
```

This works fine, unless `[DATA]` is an empty string. In that case, data just gets skipped.

I want a string like `[DATA]<US><US>[DATA]<US>` to return an array with three elements: `[DATA]`, `null` and `[DATA]`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you parametrize your `split` with `-1` as a second argument, you'll get an empty `String` where `[data]` is missing (but not `null`).

```
someString.split(String.valueOf(0x1f), -1);
```

**Explanation** from the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

> If *n* is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length.

.. where *n* is the limit, i.e. the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply loop through the array afterwards and assign empty strings as null:

```
public class StringSplitting {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String inputs = "[data]<US><US>[data]<US>";

        String[] fields = inputs.split("<US>");


        //set empty values to null
        for(int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
            if(fields[i].length() == 0){
                fields[i] = null;
            }
        }

        //print output
        for(String e: fields){
            if(e == null){
                System.out.println("null");
            }else{
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a working code

```
String s="[DATA]<US><US>[DATA]<US>";
String arr []= s.split("<US>");
for(String str :arr) {
    if(str.equals("")) {
        System.out.println("null");
    } else {
        System.out.println(str);
    }       
}
```

**Output::**

```
[DATA]
null
[DATA]
```

To be more specific as per your requirement:

```
public String [] format(String s) {     
        String arr []= s.split("<US>");     
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i].equals(""))
            {
                arr[i]=null;
            }           
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: My point was that this in fact does not work. There are no empty strings when no limit is supplied.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Please elborate. What do you mean by no limit?